# Does any extensions exit to bulk edit Related, Upsell, Cross Sell products

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to bulk edit user interface for adding related, up sell and cross sell products, actually i import my all product, i want extension selected products  related, up sell and cross sell products aded.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at below extensions:

**Free:**

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mass-product-relater-by-iksanika.html

and

**Paid:**

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mass-product-actions-by-amasty.html